# Where can I learn how to apply Tailwind CSS classes like [&>li]:pt-20 to format a list?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm unsure where to find resources that cover these rules (`[&>li]:pt-20`) in Tailwind CSS. In reality, the CSS seems to work within the Tailwind, and I'd like to understand how to use such custom classes effectively.

```html
<ul className="my-6 ml-6 list-disc [&>li]:pt-20">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seeking resources (even documentation) is off-topic for SO. CSS does not work within Tailwind. Tailwind is a CSS-Framework which means that it creates pre-defined CSS classes to which they provide normal CSS rules. However, for simplicity, it is written in pre-compiled CSS (SASS).

Comment: Thank you for your response @tacoshy.
What I mean is that `[&>li]:pt-20` can be compiled by the Tailwind into regular CSS that browsers can understand, but Tailwind can't understand `&>li:pt-20`.
What I want to know is why Tailwind can understand `[&>li]:pt-20`, and where can I learn similar syntax, such as `[&[align=center]]:text-center [&[align=right]]:text-right`, `[&:not(:first-child)]:mt-6`, and so on?
It seems that the official Tailwind website doesn't have this content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no much docs because it is just CSS: just a few things you have to keep in mind are documented [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) and [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants)